# How to change layout property if tab is selected in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic4

**Issue:**

I have 3 `ion-tab-button` under `ion-tabs` and I wanted to change their `layout` property if they are selected/active in Ionic 4. I wanted to change the `layout` property to "label-hide" if the `ion-tab-button` is inactive and to "icon-top" if it active.

**Relevant Code:**

```
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" color="primary">
    <ion-tab-button tab="dashboard">
      <ion-icon name="pie"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Dashboard</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="track">
      <ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Track</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="log">
      <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Log</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

**What I tried:**

I tried adding this property to each of the `ion-tab-button`: `layout="{{ selected ? 'icon-top' : 'label-hide'}}"` but I think selected is a property to set it to selected not get if it is selected or not. I also tried using `ViewChild` from this [link](https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/using-viewchild-in-ionic-4-to-call-component-methods/) to check if it is selected. Also tried using activated routes approach to compare the url with the tab value. Got very messy and I don't think it is a good practice.

Comment: Could you include the relevant code and what you tried already, what went wrong?

Comment: @Cray. I added what you asked for. Hope it helps clarify the issue.